# Prevent closing procexp on Esc key

Tags: sysinternals

`procexp` monitoring utility is closed when I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

<kbd>Esc</kbd> key is useful UI metaphor as it usually close unnecessary active dialogs. But it is distracting to close/exit from main application.

Can I prevent closing `procexp` on <kbd>Esc</kbd> key?